# Why does azure console write "Bad request"? (First app on nodejs in Azure)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I was trying run app on node.js in Azure, but something wrong.

**What i did**
Create web-app in Azure and deploy code from repository of bitbucket.

```
https://bitbucket.org/devsnice/nodemysql
```

After i'm entering in console and  writing "node index.js", after some time in console write "Bad request".

What do? Thank you.

p.s http://learnmysql.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I was able to run your code snippet just fine. When you say "after some time in console write 'Bad request'", what do you mean? Do you mean that when you make a http request to your server, you're getting a 400-Bad Request response?

Comment: For running app in azure, for this i used command "node index.js" in console of azure, after this i got answer "bad request" direct in console. I cannot run application.

Comment: I'm assuming he had similar issues to me - the Azure console is *REALLY* flaky. I have gotten 'Bad request' responses from some of my commands (normal, well formed commands that execute very quickly) and even some that have disappeared from my window. I've used the *EXACT SAME* commands over in the Kudu diagnostic console and they worked... same commands (like `npm install` or `npm install grunt-sass`) immediately after trying them in the Azure console